# What does having the primary key as the last column in a composite secondary index in an InnoDB table do?

Tags: mysql, innodb, primary-key, clustered-index

Say I have a 1-to-N relationship `(person_id, pet_id)`.  I have a table where `pet_id` is the primary key.

I understand that an InnoDB secondary index is essentially a B-tree where the values are the corresponding primary key values for the row.

Now, suppose one person can have thousands of pets and I often want a person's pets in order of `pet_id`.  Then it would matter if records in the secondary index are sorted by `(person_id, pet_id)` or just `person_id` with the `pet_id`'s for that `person_id` being unsorted.  Guessing the later.

So, if `person_id` is non-unique, are records physically sorted by `(person_id, pet_id)` or JUST `pet_id`?

Thanks

Comment: I suppose the last question really is: *"So, if `person_id` is non-unique, are records physically sorted by `(person_id, pet_id)` or JUST **`person_id`**?"*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. If your table has the InnoDB engine and the `PRIMARY KEY` is `(pet_id)`, then defining a secondary index as `(person_id)` or `(person_id, pet_id)` makes no difference.

The index includes the `pet_id` column as well so values are sorted as `(person_id, pet_id)` in both cases.

A query like the one you have:

```
SELECT pet_id FROM yourtable 
WHERE person_id = 127 
ORDER BY pet_id ;
```

will need to access only the index to get the values and even more, it won't need to do any sort, as the `pet_id` values are already sorted in the index. You can verify this by looking at the execution plans (`EXPLAIN`):

---

First, we try with a MyISAM table:

```
 CREATE TABLE table pets 
 ( pet_id int not null auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, 
   person_id int not null, 
   INDEX person_ix (person_id)
 ) ENGINE = myisam ;

INSERT INTO pets (person_id) 
VALUES (1),(2),(3),(1),(2),(3),(4),(1),(8),(1),(2),(3) ;

mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT pet_id FROM pets 
               WHERE person_id = 2  
               ORDER BY pet_id asc \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: pets
         type: ref
possible_keys: person_ix
          key: person_ix
      key_len: 4
          ref: const
         rows: 3
        Extra: Using where; Using filesort
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Notice the filesort!**

Now, MyISAM with composite index:

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS pets ;

 CREATE TABLE table pets 
 ( pet_id int not null auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, 
   person_id int not null, 
   INDEX person_ix (person_id, pet_id)            -- composite index
 ) ENGINE = myisam ;

INSERT INTO pets (person_id) 
VALUES (1),(2),(3),(1),(2),(3),(4),(1),(8),(1),(2),(3) ;


mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT pet_id FROM pets 
               WHERE person_id = 2  
               ORDER BY pet_id asc \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: pets
         type: ref
possible_keys: person_ix
          key: person_ix
      key_len: 4
          ref: const
         rows: 3
        Extra: Using where; Using index
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Filesort is gone**, as expected.

---

Now lets try the same with InnoDB engine:

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS pets ;

 CREATE TABLE table pets 
 ( pet_id int not null auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, 
   person_id int not null, 
   INDEX person_ix (person_id)            -- simple index
 ) ENGINE = innodb ;                      -- InnoDB engine

INSERT INTO pets (person_id) 
VALUES (1),(2),(3),(1),(2),(3),(4),(1),(8),(1),(2),(3) ;

mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT pet_id FROM pets 
               WHERE person_id = 2  
               ORDER BY pet_id asc \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: pets
         type: ref
possible_keys: person_ix
          key: person_ix
      key_len: 4
          ref: const
         rows: 3
        Extra: Using where; Using index
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**No filesort either!** Even though the index does not explicitly have the `pet_id` column, the values are there and sorted. You can check that if you define the index with `(person_id, pet_id)`, the `EXPLAIN` is identical.

Lets actually do it, with InnoDB and the composite index:

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS pets ;

 CREATE TABLE table pets 
 ( pet_id int not null auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, 
   person_id int not null, 
   INDEX person_ix (person_id, pet_id)    -- composite index
 ) ENGINE = innodb ;                      -- InnoDB engine

INSERT INTO pets (person_id) 
VALUES (1),(2),(3),(1),(2),(3),(4),(1),(8),(1),(2),(3) ;

mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT pet_id FROM pets 
               WHERE person_id = 2  
               ORDER BY pet_id asc \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: pets
         type: ref
possible_keys: person_ix
          key: person_ix
      key_len: 4
          ref: const
         rows: 3
        Extra: Using where; Using index
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Identical plans** with the previous case.

---

To be 100% sure, I also run the last 2 cases (InnoDB engine, with single and composite indexes) enabling the `file_per_table` setting and adding a few thousands rows in the table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ... ;
CREATE TABLE ... ;

mysql> INSERT INTO pets (person_id) 
       VALUES (1),(2),(3),(1),(2),(3),(4),(1),(8),(1),(2),(3) ;
Query OK, 12 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 12  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> INSERT INTO pets (person_id) 
       VALUES (1),(2),(3),(1),(2),(3),(4),(1),(8),(1),(2),(3),(127) ;
Query OK, 13 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 13  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> INSERT INTO pets (person_id) 
       VALUES (1),(2),(3),(1),(2),(3),(4),(1),(8),(1),(2),(3),(127) ;
Query OK, 13 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 13  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> INSERT INTO pets (person_id) 
       SELECT a.person_id+b.person_id-1 
       FROM pets a CROSS JOIN pets b CROSS JOIN pets c ;
Query OK, 54872 rows affected (0.47 sec)
Records: 54872  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

In both cases, checking the actual file sizes, yields **identical results**:

```
ypercube@apollo:~$ sudo ls -la /var/lib/mysql/x/ | grep pets
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql     8604 Apr 21 07:25 pets.frm
-rw-rw----  1 mysql mysql 11534336 Apr 21 07:25 pets.ibd
```

Comment: Assuming InnoDB works similarly in this respect to MS SQL Server, there *is* a difference between an index on `(<some_column>)` and `(<some_column>, <pk>)` because `ON (<some_column>)` is equivalent to `ON (<some_column>) INCLUDE (<pk>)` and not `ON (<some_column>, <pk>)`. In most circumstances this has pretty much zero significance, *but* if your PK is random (i.e. a UUID) then `ON (<s_c>,<pk>)` can lead to extra fragmentation or if your PK is meaningful other than being a key and you might `ORDER BY s_c, pk` then such sorts will be faster as the index is already fully in order.

Comment: @DavidSpillett Right. MySQL has no `INCLUDE (columns)` functionality though. That's another reason I concluded that the `(s_c)` index is equivalent to `(s_c, pk)`.

Comment: I can't find documentation to back me up (so I may be misremembering) but I'm fairly sure I've read that InnoDB doesn't keep the PK in stable order in secondary indexes unless asked to. Though the difference is minor anyway. When I next have time to play with mySQL I'll have to test the theory...

Comment: @DavidSpillett - https://blog.jcole.us/2013/01/10/the-physical-structure-of-records-in-innodb/ the *Secondary indexes* section - *"There is one thing of note for secondary index non-leaf pages: the clustered key fields (PKV) are included in the record and is considered part of the record’s key, not its value."* so it orders them as least on the level of pages. Not sure exactly how it is inside a single page from that description, but even if they are not, that is simply solved by a small buffer - read PKs from one page, sort (max ~500 ? items) and fetch ordered so may be irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

According to the MySQL Documentation on the [Clustered and Secondary Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-index-types.html)

> **How Secondary Indexes Relate to the Clustered Index**
>
> All indexes other than the clustered index are known as secondary indexes. ***In InnoDB, each record in a secondary index contains the primary key columns for the row, as well as the columns specified for the secondary index***. InnoDB uses this primary key value to search for the row in the clustered index.
>
> If the primary key is long, the secondary indexes use more space, so it is advantageous to have a short primary key.

Therefore, adding the PRIMARY KEY to a secondary index is definitely redundant. Your index entry would like `(person_id, pet_id, pet_id)`. This would also needlessly bloat the secondary index by having 2 copies of the `PRIMARY KEY`.

For the index with `(person_id)`, if you were to run a query like this

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE person_id = 127 ORDER BY pet_id;
```

The `PRIMARY KEY` would be fully engaged in this query and produces the results ordered by `PRIMARY KEY` anyway. From a physical standpoint, the rows are ordered by insertion order. If the pet_id is AUTO_INCREMENT, then it is order by the auto number.

Comment: Afaik InnoDB won't "bloat" the index by adding the PK column second time when it is already present. You can even use it to specify a different order of PK columns for multicolumn key: when you have PK `(owner_id, pet_id)` but you can create a key `(vet_id, pet_id[, owner_id])` to utilize different column order.

Answer (score 2):

Tip 1:

```
PRIMARY KEY(x, id),
INDEX(id) -- where `id` is `AUTO_INCREMENT`
```

is perfectly valid.  It has the performance advantage of being more efficient when many queries need to find multiple rows `WHERE x = 123`.  That is, it is slightly more efficient than the 'obvious'

```
PRIMARY KEY(id),
INDEX(x, id)
```

The only rule about `AUTO_INCREMENT` (for InnoDB) is that `id` must be the *first* column in *some* index.  Note that that rule says nothing about `PRIMARY` or `UNIQUE` or 'only column'.

The tip is useful for huge tables that are often fetched by `x` together with other stuff.

Tip 2:  Suppose you have

```
SELECT name FROM tbl WHERE person_id = 12 AND pet_id = 34;
```

This is a "covering" index:

```
INDEX(person_id, pet_id, name)
```

That is, the entire query can be done inside the index's BTree.  The EXPLAIN will say "Using index".